# Do groovy bindings exist for a class?

Tags: groovy

I've a simple class with a `main()` method from which I want to access the script bindings.

```
class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    binding.variables.each{ 
      println it.key
      println it.value 
    }
  }
}
```

Does the implicit `binding` variable exist for a simple class such as this or is it only for scripts?

I realize I can pass it into the method / the constructor of the object. But since I'd like to keep this as a pure class file and not a script, I cannot do that.

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is the question?

Comment: The question was to know if that could be made to compile without turning it into a `script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a property of a [Script](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java) instance. Look at the source, you'll see that a `Binding` is only a delegate, used in `getProperty` or `setProperty`.